# Is it possible to show keyboard on button click for mobile view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In MVC application I have a requirement such that whenever a textbox associated to a field is clicked

1. The keyboard pop up for mobile view should be hidden
2. There should be a small button shown
3. Upon clicking on this button the keyboard should show up.

The reason behind such a requirement is that we have a hardware device which can transfer the value directly to the textbox so keyboard should be hidden and when there is a need to modify the value sent by this hardware so user can click on the button and after keyboard popup the value can be modified.

I've achieved point number 1 & 2, kindly help me to achieve point number 3 (if it's possible)

Below is the code snippet of my .cshtml file:

Textbox:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     <input type="number" value="" name="FeatureList" id=@textBoxId maxlength="13" class="form-control-new  " />
</div>
```

Keyboard show/hide button:

```
<div>
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="btnKeyboard"> Keyboard </button>
</div>
```

Textbox click event:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(this).on('click', "#dynamicControls input[type='text']", function () {
            debugger;
               $("#btnKeyboard").hide(); 

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may disable the textbox and enable it only when the user clicks the button so that the mobile device will show the keyboard.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(this).on('click', "#btnKeyboard", function () {
            debugger;
               $('input').prop( "disabled", false ); 
               $('input').focus();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
     <input type="number" value="" name="FeatureList" id=@textBoxId maxlength="13" class="form-control-new" disabled />
</div>


Keyboard show/hide button : 

<div>
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="btnKeyboard"> Keyboard </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding *disabled* property for keyboard did hide it from poping up after clicking on textbox but then it was also not possible to transfer the data from hardware to the selected textbox. If I remove the *disabled* property it is possible to send the data from hardware to textbox but I don't want the keyboard to occupy the screen space unnecessarily.